# Interoperate with typescript in dart

Tags: angular, dart

I am using angular2dart and want to know, ifsomeone do a very nice e.g. components in angular2 typescript, can I import that to dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Angular2 TS components can't be used in Angular2 Dart.
You would need to port it.

You can run another Angular2 TS application side-by-side on the same page as the Angular2 Dart application, but that's it.

With Dart-JS-interop TypeScript libraries can be made available to Dart using https://github.com/dart-lang/js_facade_gen, but Angular2 Dart won't recognize anything as Angular2 component. This are then used pure JavaScript libraries with a nice typed Dart interface.

Comment: So it is not possible to use for third-party angular2 that is written in typescript in dart. Would you use typescript or dart angular2 version?

Comment: I only use Dart but that's my personal preference. For others TS might work better. I'd discourage using ES6 though (but also only a personal opinion).

Comment: I wrote an app based angular2dart and I fall in love with the language. Would you say, angular2dart is production ready?

Comment: I think it actually is production ready but that depends on your requirements. I also like Dart. As you mentioned there are less components available for Dart but they start to emerge https://dart-lang.github.io/angular2_components_example/.

Comment: How to install the components?

Comment: Like any Dart package. Add it to `pubspec.yaml` `dependencies` and run `pub get` or `pub upgrade`. See the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular2_components `Installing` tab - but it's adviceable to add a version constraint `angular2_components: '^0.1.1'`

Comment: you are very active in the dart community and why do you prefer angular2dart over angular2 typescript?

Comment: I prefer Dart over TS not Angular2 Dart over Angular2 TS ;-). I'm working with Dart since 2014 and have no intention to switch. I enjoy that I can use Angular2 with Dart.

Comment: Yes, ok I will use dart on my next project. Thanks